# How to write float numbers to CSV file, without comma in Python?

Tags: python, csv

Imagine that I have a list like this :

```
list1 = [12.34, 17.68, 19.22]
```

Now I want to write each numbers in one row of a CSV file. So after that I changed the type of numbers to string, I do this :

```
with open(output_file_name, 'w') as ofile:
        outfile = csv.writer(ofile)
        outfile.writerows(list1)
```

and the result will be something like this :

```
1,2,.,3,4
1,7,.,6,8
1,9,.,2,2
```

How can I delete these commas between the numbers?

Note :

1. I want to show each number in a row
2. I don't want anything for delimiter.
3. I use Python 3.9.7
4. I know that .csv file might not be suitable for this case, but this is a project that somebody wants from me, as an exam !

Comment: Do you want them in a column or a row? Do you use Python 3.4+?

Comment: Go to the docs and search for the word `delimiter` to see all the ways to set this.

Comment: By definition, a CSV file is *comma* separated, is there an advantage in your use case to be gained by removing the separator?

Comment: @S3DEV, yeah but you can change it

Comment: @PCM - Yes, one can certainly change the defined separator used by the writer, but that’s not my point.  A ‘CSV’ file is (by definition) *comma* separated.  Therefore the OP does not want a CSV file.

Comment: @S3DEV yeah you are right, why write to csv file , when you do not want delimiter.

Comment: @PCM - Exactly.  :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing `list1` as the list of *rows,* so the `csv` module does its best to figure out what you mean.

Probably what you actually mean is

```py
    outfile.writerow(list1)
```

(notice the singular `writerow`) which writes all the values as a single row.

Or, if you want one number per row, try

```py
    outfile.writerows([x] for x in list1)
```

In your attempt, `list1` is converted to a list of strings, and then each string is split into a sequence to produce a row.

To reiterate, the argument to `csv.writer.writerow` should be a list of cell values, and the argument to `writerows` should be a list of such rows.

Answer (score 1):

writerows will treat each element of the array as an row and attempt to iterate over the entries in that row, that is why for a string it splits it into individual characters.  if you want to write each number on a separate line then use:

```
with open(output_file_name, 'w') as ofile:
        outfile = csv.writer(ofile)
        outfile.writerows(([str(i)] for i in list1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `pathlib` to easily write things

```py
from pathlib import Path

# create file and write text
out_file = Path('example.csv')

# data
list_1 = [12.34 , 17.68 , 19.22]

out_file.write_text('column1, ')
with out_file.open(mode='a') as f:
    # write to file
    {f.write(f'\n{item}, ') for item in list_1}
    
    
# read contents
contents = out_file.read_text()
print(contents)
```

Comment: This produces a file which technically is a CSV file as long as none of the rows contain quotes or commas. If the code should extend to arbitrary data, this won't work (though using CSV if you only have one value per line is silly, anyway; just save as a plain old text file, which is exactly what this does).

Comment: It can be extended to deal with all of that. Example we can do preprocessing of item before adding it. I will argue that this way, we have more control over what is written.

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv

list1 = [12.34, 17.68, 19.22]

with open('output_file_name', 'w') as ofile:
    outfile = csv.writer(ofile, delimiter=" ")
    outfile.writerow(list1)
```

This should works for You I have checked it out in editor :-D
Best regards ;-)

Comment: This is not what OP wants though.

Answer (score -1):

One quick way to do this, would be to make use of the *.join()* method. This method can take items from an iterator (such as your list) and join them together separated by whatever character(s) you'd like. You can do it like this to have your items separated by only a space:

```
with open(output_file_name, 'w') as ofile:
    outfile = csv.writer(ofile)
    outfile.writerows(' '.join(list1))
```

If you don't want a space between the items, but instead want them all stuck together do this instead:

```
outfile.writerows(''.join(list1))
```

Comment: Do you know how CSV works?

Comment: He doesn't want a comma separated value list, quite the opposite....